# ODE Solution in Carr's Randomized American Put

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options, differential-equations

In Carr's 1998 paper [Randomization and the American Put](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8992/0704c2a16137c82354939cb0307abd0f562c.pdf), he sets up the following ODE for the value of an American put with expiration given by the first jump time of a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 1/T$ (Eq. 10 in link):
$$
\frac{\sigma^2}{2}S^2 P^{(1)}_{SS}(S) + rSP^{(1)}_S(S) - rP^{(1)}(S) = \lambda[P^{(1)}(S) - (K - S)^+], \qquad S > \underline{S}_1 \quad (1)
$$
subject to the boundary conditions
$$
\lim_{S \, \uparrow \infty} P^{(1)}(S) = 0, \qquad \lim_{S \, \downarrow \underline{S}_1} P^{(1)}(S) = K - \underline{S}_1, \qquad \lim_{S \, \downarrow \underline{S}_1} P^{(1)}_S(S) = -1\;.
$$
Here $P^{(1)}(S)$ is the randomized American put value and $\underline{S}_1 < K$ is the (unknown) optimal exercise boundary.  Carr gives the following solution, which I am struggling to derive myself:
\begin{align*}
P^{(1)}(S) = 
\begin{cases}
p^{(1)}(S) + b^{(1)}(S) \qquad & \text{if } S > K \\
KR - S + c^{(1)}(S) + b^{(1)}(S) \qquad & \text{if } S \in (\underline{S}_1, K) \\
K - S \qquad & \text{if } S \leq \underline{S}_1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Here, $p^{(1)}(S)$ is the randomized value of a European put paying $(K-S)^+$ at the first jump:
$$
p^{(1)}(S) = \left(\frac{S}{K}\right)^{\gamma - \epsilon} (qKR - \hat{q}K), \qquad S > K
$$
where
$$
\gamma = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{r}{\sigma^2}, \qquad R = \frac{1}{1 + rT}, \qquad \epsilon = \sqrt{\gamma^2 + \frac{2}{R\sigma^2 T}}
$$
and
$$
p = \frac{\epsilon - \gamma}{2\epsilon}, \qquad q = 1-p, \qquad \hat{p} = \frac{\epsilon - \gamma + 1}{2\epsilon}, \qquad \hat{q} = 1 - \hat{p} \;.
$$
The quantity $b^{(1)}(S)$ is described as the present value of interest received below the critical stock price $\underline{S}_1$ until the first jump,
$$
b^{(1)}(S) = \left(\frac{S}{\underline{S}_1}\right)^{\gamma - \epsilon} qKRrT \;.
$$
Finally, $c^{(1)}(S)$ is the randomized value of a European call paying $(S - K)^+$ at the first jump time,
$$
c^{(1)}(S) = \left(\frac{S}{K}\right)^{\gamma + \epsilon} (\hat{p}K - pKR), \qquad S < K\;.
$$

Here's what I did for the case $S \in (\underline{S}_1, K)$, for which I'm not arriving at Carr's solution.  Using the change of variables $x \mapsto \log S$, it's easy to show the homogeneous solution to $(1)$ is
$$
P^{(1)}_{homo}(S) = c_1 S^{\gamma + \epsilon} + c_2 S^{\gamma - \epsilon}
$$
and that the particular solution is
$$
P^{(1)}(S) = c_1 S^{\gamma + \epsilon} + c_2 S^{\gamma - \epsilon} + RK - S\;.
$$
Using the boundary conditions $\lim_{S \, \downarrow \underline{S}_1} P^{(1)}(S) = K - \underline{S}_1$ and $\lim_{S \, \downarrow \underline{S}_1} P^{(1)}_S(S) = -1$, I get that
\begin{align*}
c_1 & = \underline{S}_1^{-\gamma - \epsilon}(pK - pKR), \\
c_2 & = \underline{S}_1^{\epsilon - \gamma}qKRrT
\end{align*}
This is *almost* the correct solution, if only we had $c_1 = K^{-\gamma - \epsilon}(\hat{p}K - pKR)$.  That is, replacing $\underline{S}_1$ with $K$ and the first $p$ with $\hat{p}$.  Can anyone spot where I may have made a mistake?